# Connecting to a Bluetooth device you only know the address of

Tags: android, bluetooth, mac-address

I'm trying to create an application that, in simplest terms, sends its bluetooth mac address to a server (via 3G connection), then the application on a parallel device receives it (again via 3G), and tries to connect via Bluetooth to the first device. 
Is it possible without the second device running discovery and then comparing the discovered addresses with the one it got from the server.

In other words is there something like `"BT.connect(macaddress);"`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. Discovery is not needed if you already know the mac address. You can also look into an insecure Bluetooth connection to avoid pairing, using [BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.UUID%29), but this is only available from API level 10 and above.

Just be aware of the security issues.